# WindowLicker-like framework with SWT support

Tags: swt, gui-testing, swtbot

Is there a testing framework with SWT support which works like WindowLicker? I.e., drives the actual user interface instead of firing events programmatically (like SWTBot)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project on Google code called WindowTester might satisfy your request..

[WindowTester Pro User Guide on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wintester/html/index.html)

[SWT test sample](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wintester/html/gettingstarted/swt_sampletest.html)